# Why is `str` not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python I wrote:

```
from base64 import b64encode
import os
import uuid
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def scan_network_for_list_of_ips(dest_network = '10.10.10.0/24'):
    print(' '.join(['Scanning',dest_network]))
    file_name = 'nmap_' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.txt'
```

But I'm getting:

```
"str" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable)
```

What does that mean? str isn't a variable...

When I run my code I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'str' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Show what's above your code.

Comment: Done, interestingly this happens only inside my function

Comment: I can’t reproduce this.  The code (obviously) works — and you haven’t posted the entire code, since nothing is calling the function. And you almost certainly haven’t posted the entire function, either.

Comment: You need to show what follows after the code. The error message indicates that you declare a variable `str` somewhere later, which hides the builtin `str` function. If so, try to rename your local variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code results in your described behavior. This is because you declare a local variable named `str` somewhere later within the function. This does hide the builtin `str` function, resulting in this deceptive message from python.

To solve this issue, you need to rename your local `str` variable to something different.

```
from base64 import b64encode
import os
import uuid
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def scan_network_for_list_of_ips(dest_network = '10.10.10.0/24'):
    print(' '.join(['Scanning',dest_network]))
    file_name = 'nmap_' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.txt'
    # some code
    str = "..." # hides the above used internal builtin str function and must be renamed to something different
    # some code

scan_network_for_list_of_ips()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using `str` as a variable *somewhere* in your function. If you assign to a variable anywhere in a function, it will be treated as local throughout the function, even before the assignment.

Answer (score -3):

Try to use

> file_name = 'nmap_' + uuid.uuid4.get() + '.txt'

If it's not the problem try to use the .get() in an other way, for me it's the solution but don't know all of your program so that depends.